# Is $[1,\infty ) $closed?

Tags: real-analysis

If $(-\infty ,1) $ is open, then the compliment should be closed. Right?

I'm asking because the interval otherwise looks like a half-open interval.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is closed. Note that $\mathbb R \left(\subseteq \mathbb R\right)$ is both, open **and** closed.

Comment: Note that $\infty\notin\mathbb R$, so $[0,\infty) = [0,\infty]\cap\mathbb R$ ;)

Comment: It's not a half-open interval. The notation $[0,\infty)$ looks that way, but it's only a convenience--the right endpoint is not an endpoint at all. The set is a closed ray. A half-open interval is like $[a,b)$ with the endpoints in the space.

Comment: It is complement, not compliment. But one usually prefers the latter to the former.

Answer (score 2):

It depends from the topological space. If you are talking about the usual topology in $R$, then it is a closed set.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1. If an interval is open, every point of that interval is an interior point.
2. If it is closed, it contains all its limit points.

Answer (score 1):

A set is closed iff it contains all its limit points.

A limit point is a point $x$ in the set such that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there exists a $y$ also in the set such that $y \neq x$ and $|y-x |< \epsilon $.

So, if $x \in (1, \infty)$, then by the denseness property of the reals we may take $\epsilon$ sufficiently small so that there exists a $y \in (1,\infty)$ such that $|y-x|<\epsilon$.

Similiarly, if $x=1$ there exists a $y \in (1, \infty)$ such that $y-x < \epsilon$